# What version of Leaflet does Flickr use?

Tags: flickr

As a user of the [SmoothWheel](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/smoothwheel/) Firefox extension, I sometimes come across apps that capture the scroll event but don't prevent it to propagate further, resulting in, for example, a map zooming while the page simultaneously scrolls down.

I've reported the issue [for Leaflet](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/916) and for the [ACE editor](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1043), and it has since been [fixed in Leaflet 0.5](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#browser-bugfixes-1) (released 17 January 2013). However, the issue still appears in Flickr. To make sure that what's missing for Flickr is an upgrade to the latest version, I would like to know what version of Leaflet do they use, but looking at the page source wasn't enlightening.

So... what is the version of Leaflet that Flickr uses?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about the underlying technology of a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [code.flickr.com](http://code.flickr.net/2012/06/29/the-great-map-update-of-2012/) blog, I found out that they actually maintain [a fork of Leaflet](https://github.com/flickr/Leaflet). It seems like it was never updated or tweaked on any way, being simply a frozen version of Leaflet at a commit from [June 2, 2012](https://github.com/flickr/Leaflet/commits/master), which corresponds to [version 0.4](https://github.com/flickr/Leaflet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). Looks like an upgrade is in order :)